# Why is this bash program going into an infinite loop?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter number of loops"
read count
echo $count
if [ $count -eq 0 ]
 then
    echo "The count cannot be zero. Enter a number again"
    read count
fi

while [ $count -gt 0 ]
do
    echo "Loop numner $count"
    count = `expr $count - 1`
done
```

I am trying to simulate a Java counter in bash. Does this exist?

Comment: Are `for ((count=n; count > 0; --count)); do ...;  done` or `count=$n; while ((count--)); do ... ; done` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have space in between your assignment statement as below:

```
count = `expr $count - 1`
     ^  ^
```

Remove the space between "=" like below:

```
count=`expr $count - 1`
Output
Enter number of loops
10
10
Loop numner 10
Loop numner 9
Loop numner 8
Loop numner 7
Loop numner 6
Loop numner 5
Loop numner 4
Loop numner 3
Loop numner 2
Loop numner 1
```

Note apart, backticks are discouraged and you should be using something like:

```
 count=$(expr $count - 1)
```

Comment: thank you. Is there any particular reason why backticks are discouraged?

Comment: @Ralphyabro: they can't be nested without a headache. `echo $(echo $(echo hello))` is fine... how do you do that with backticks?

Comment: Thanks gniourf_gniourf, @Ralphyabro you could even refer [wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rock solid rewriting of your script, to show you how it's usually done:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -rep "Enter number of loops: " count
    if [[ $count = +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
        ((count=10#$count))
        ((count>0)) && break
        printf 'The count cannot be zero. Enter a number again.\n'
     else
        printf 'Please enter a valid number.\n'
     fi
done

while ((count>0)); do
    printf 'Loop number %s\n' "$count"
    ((--count))
done
```

- Using `read` with the `-r` flag to have backslashes not escape some characters (this should be the default), with the `-e` option so that `read` uses readline: it's more comfortable for the user, and with the `-p` option to specify the prompt.
- I completely revisited the logic you're using to read user's input: `read` is run in an infinite loop that can only be broken when user enters a valid number. With your method, a user could enter invalid data twice, and the loop would have run with random arguments. Not good.
- To check that user input is valid, I'm using pattern matching: `[[ $count = +([[:digit:]]) ]]` that is true if and only if `count` expands to a string of one or more digits, then I'm making sure that Bash will treat `count` in radix 10: in arithmetic context, `10#$count` treats count in radix 10. Without this, an input like `08` or `09` would make some subsequent parts fail, as a leading zero means, for Bash, that the number should be interpreted in radix 8, hence `08` is not valid!
- The final loop is written with Bash's arithmetic context `((...))`. You don't need the external `expr` to perform simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bash arithmetic expansion:

```
    count="$((count -1))"
```

I would also suggest making the first test -le not -eq, in case the user types in a negative integer, and quote it in case the user types nothing at all.

```
    if [ "$count" -le 0 ]
```

So your code would be:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Enter number of loops"
    read count
    echo $count
    if [ "$count" -le 0 ]
     then
        echo "The count cannot be zero. Enter a number again"
        read count
    fi

    while [ $count -gt 0 ]
    do
        echo "Loop numner $count"
        count="$((count - 1))"
    done
```